# Is it possible to run XML through two stylesheets in a browser?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsltforms

If I have an XML document, I can add the processing instruction

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="MYXML.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

to the XML, which I can then use to convert to (x)html, apply CSS and other markup in the browser.

However, I would also like to use [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms), which itself requires being applied as a processing instruction like below:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="yes"?>
```

Is it possible to set the result output of an stylesheet in a browser to in turn be run through a stylesheet, so I can convert the XML to HTML and in turn have XSLTForms run, or is there some other method that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I think you can do it, but only by writing some Javascript to control the processing.

Comment: Think thats the approach I'll go with, thanks for your help!